# Applying ACLs in a SIP-400 Card (Configuring IP Subscriber Awareness over Ethernet )

Tags: cisco, cisco-7600, vrf

Good morning,

I am trying to apply an ACL in a 7609 SIP-400 Card used to allow PPPoE on the 7609 (with a SPA-5X1G). A Pbr doesn't work when applied to the virtual-template (as it does on a 7200 Router). I have been reading [Configuring IP Subscriber Awareness over Ethernet](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst4500/12-2/15-02SG/configuration/guide/config/vrf.html#wp1079187), but am not skilled with containers, VRF and so on...

Anyone could tell me some link/info or something to improve my knowledge about this?

Thanks in advance!!